# HTML5 contenteditable - placing the cursor before a non editable display block element

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to place a span within a contenteditable element which sort of represents a tag/separator as such:

```css
.tag {
  display:block;
  background-color:red;
}

.edit-box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" class="edit-box">
    <span class="tag" contenteditable="false">NON EDITABLE</span>How to style the span element so it's possible to place the cursor at the start?
</div>
```

I'm trying to edit text before and after the span element, but it's impossible to place the cursor just before the element.
Any ideas how to style the span element to allow a more flexible cursor movement around it.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mub640zo/)

Comment: `display: inline-block;` ?

Comment: @Maximus er.. how stupid of me. exactly, and setting the width to 100% solves it. Can you post an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: sure, posted my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these styles:

```
.tag {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try suppressing events for editing the span content. I was compelled to separate the span and div elements, but it works correctly in IE11, even when they are together. I reckon, there is an issue of intercepting in other browsers. But the idea appears to be clear. The only thing you'll have to do is changing your style to make it show previous way.

```js
function handle(e)
{
 if (e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode != 37)
 return false;
}
```

```css
.tag {
  display:block;
  background-color:red;
}

.edit-box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="tag" contenteditable="true" onkeydown="return handle(event)">NON EDITABLE</span>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" class="edit-box">How to style the span element so it's possible to place the cursor before?
</div>
```

Comment: The span element should be within the contenteditable div. You can think of it as a tag. I want to be able to move the cursor so that I can type text before and after the tag.